# Why telegram bot not sending the message?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Why bot not sending message?
My code:

```
import telegram
import requests

bot_token = 'token***'

my_bot = telegram.Bot(token=bot_token)

def get_chat_id(bot_token):
    request = requests.post(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/getUpdates')
    result = request.json()['result'][0]['message']['chat']['id']
    return result

chat_id = get_chat_id(bot_token)

msg = 'My PC'
my_bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=msg)
```

Python 3.11.5, Telegram 20.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my telegram bot I use the next config

```
    #Token of the telegram bot

    TOKEN = "yours"

    #Id for the chat
    chat_id  = "the_chat_id"

    msj_err = "Bot is alive"
 
 
 
 requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot'+TOKEN+'/sendMessage?chat_id='+chat_id+'&text='+msj_err)
```

The chat_id is something i needed to set manually, because sometimes it does't take it. Now this bot has been working for 3 months.

The problem I think is that the chat id is not correct. Try to extract the chat id and compare of what is getting in your request.

Comment: Yep, it's working.